# Editing Div Text At Click Position

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a DIV which contains some text. When a user clicks on some content in the DIV, I want to enable him to edit the content at that position.

```
<div id='Note'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <br />
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br />
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip <br />
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse <br />
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <br />
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`contenteditable` will do it in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.0+, Safari 1.3+, Opera 9+, Chrome:

```
<div id="Note" contenteditable="true">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <br />
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br />
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip <br />
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse <br />
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <br />
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
</div>
```

Comment: i'm able to add stuff, thank you...but then things like backspace and delete don't seem to work.

Comment: Really? Works fine for me. In which browser?

Comment: have reported this as a bug for Firefox. Bug 571776 and 571694.

Comment: Interesting. The more I see of Firefox's implementation of `contenteditable`, the more I'm convinced they've made a bit of a botched job of it. `designMode` generally works much better. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use `<textarea>` element. Then you can edit text inside it at any position.

Comment: I agree with Kate, that would make a lot of sense. Besides, how do you allow the user to edit a DIV content, unless you convert it to a textarea. May be you could elaborate a little on what you are trying to achieve? There's usually more than one way of doing things.

Comment: i am doing a JavaScript-based note-editor (memonaut). I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to Google Notebook, where you can click on a note to edit it. The cursor lands up where the user-clicked.

Comment: You cat set <textarea disabled="disabled"> when user reads notes and  <textarea disabled=""> when user click textarea to edit.